# Why is the Body Onload not work with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't why this is happening and it probably just a basic mistake but my `body` is able to call a function because:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: changeImg is not defined`

Here is my relevant PHP/HTML:

`<?php print("<body onLoad='javascript:changeImg(year_" . $p_date[0] . ")'>"); ?>`

And my JavaScript functions:

```
var currentImg = 0;
var totalImg = 0;
var stored_year = 0;

$("#next-button").click(function() {
    if (currentImg == totalImg) {
        currentImg = 0;
    }
    else {
        currentImg++;
    }
    changeImg();
});

$("#previous-button").click(function() {
    if (currentImg == 0) {
        currentImg = totalImg;
    }
    else {
        currentImg--;
    }
    changeImg();
});

function changeImg(galleryYear) {

    if (galleryYear = stored_year) {


        $("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + galleryYear.x_src[currentImg] + "'>");
        $("#gallery-title").html(galleryYear.x_title[currentImg]);
        $("#gallery-medium").html(galleryYear.x_medium[currentImg]);
        $("#gallery-size").html(galleryYear.x_size[currentImg]);
        $("#gallery-date").html(galleryYear.x_date[currentImg]);

        var userCurrent = currentImg + 1;
        var userTotal = galleryYear.x_id.length;

        $("#current-post").html(userCurrent);
        $("#post-total").html(userTotal);

        var galWidth = $("#gallery-image" > "img").width();
        $("#gallery").width(galWidth);

    }
    else {

        currentImg = 0;
        $("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + galleryYear.x_src[currentImg] + "'>");
        $("#gallery-title").html(galleryYear.x_title[currentImg]);
        $("#gallery-medium").html(galleryYear.x_medium[currentImg]);
        $("#gallery-size").html(galleryYear.x_size[currentImg]);
        $("#gallery-date").html(galleryYear.x_date[currentImg]);

        var userCurrent = currentImg + 1;
        var userTotal = galleryYear.x_id.length;

        $("#current-post").html(userCurrent);
        $("#post-total").html(userTotal);

        var galWidth = $("#gallery-image" > "img").width();
        $("#gallery").width(galWidth);

        $("#gallery-type").html('<img id="gallery-switch" alt="" src="images/gallery-icon.png" onClick="gallerySwitch()">');

        stored_year = galleryYear;
    }

}
```

It was working earlier but why not now?

Comment: What have you changed since "earlier"?  Have you tried using the developer tools (F12) in the browser to see if there are any syntax errors in your RENDERED code?

Comment: Careful, this : `if (galleryYear = stored_year) {`should be `if (galleryYear === stored_year) {`

Comment: @freefaller I changed a few things but went back and undid them to restore it to its working state, only now it doesn't even work and I can't figure this out.

Comment: @RomainBraun fixed that but it didn't fix the function not being found.

Comment: The logic error is indeed an error (it's a sematic one)... but you're complaining about is a **syntax** error.  For that you'll need the developer tools

Comment: Is your `changeImg` function defined within a `document.ready(...)`?

Comment: @freefaller I think it must be something with logic at this point, as there are no errors in this according to different software.

Comment: @JasonP No, it's outside of it.

Comment: OK, last comment, and then I'm outta here, because you're not listening to me.  If it was a logic error, the function would "exist" for the browser to be able to call it.  If you have "defined" the function in the code, but the browser can't see it, it means there is a SYNTAX error somewhere in your page.  That syntax error (maybe something like stray `{` or `}`) means that the function effectively doesn't exist any more.  Good luck finding it

Comment: defining the `changeImg()` out side the `document.ready(...)` is the main problem, define inside it will do fix.

Answer (score 1):

When it says that the function is **not definied**, this normally means, that the javascript where you declare the function has to be called BEFORE the code that calles the function.

In you example (which would be better if you pasted the whole code) I guess you should put the JS code in the `<head>` tag, which should solve your problem.

Another option would be to use the document.ready event, or document.load event, but not bound directly in the tag, but at the end od the body.

Comment: Isn't Javascript supposed to come right before the `body` closes?  And because that's where my script links are, the `body` shouldn't hit the `onLoad` checkpoint until those scripts are fully loaded.

Comment: That would be true if the OP hadn't already shown that the function call is being made in the `<body onload="">`

Comment: why printing with php body onLoad(... ? it comes before any javascript

Comment: @vodich the php is inserting a variable that is generated before my header.

Comment: vodich - That is why I say, we would need the whole script to see when he loads it. But if you need JS in the body tag, it definitly must be defined before this - so it means in the head

Comment: j0sh1e - there are more diffrerent practices on where to put JS. the on load event will not fire before all is loaded, that is true. It is hard to explain and understand, I am not that a guru in JS, but the code is being read by the interpreter sequential, and if he sees a function which was not defined yet - the error occurs

Comment: @j0sh1e   <body onLoad='javascript:changeImg(year_<?php echo $p_date[0];?>)'> also you can do that on document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

I think in you code, what is `year_" . $p_date[0] . "`.

This might be a value. But you have passes this as an variable.

Or may be somehow the function **changeImg** is not loading or there is some error before **changeImg** declared.

Sometimes if there is some error or exception in JavaScript, then the function after it shows not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the body of the function. check the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/rajanrawat/3pCvX/

```
var currentImg = 0;
var totalImg = 0;
var stored_year = 0;

$("#next-button").click(function() {
if (currentImg == totalImg) {
    currentImg = 0;
}
else {
    currentImg++;
}
changeImg();
});

$("#previous-button").click(function() {
if (currentImg == 0) {
    currentImg = totalImg;
}
else {
    currentImg--;
}
changeImg();
});

function changeImg(galleryYear) {

alert('in here');

}
```

it gets the function. Maybe you are not binding it at ondom ready or inside

```
$(document).ready()
```